# Beginner - While() - Optimization

Tags: c, embedded, pic

I am new in embedded development and few times ago I red some code about a PIC24xxxx.

```
void i2c_Write(char data) {
    while (I2C2STATbits.TBF) {};

    IFS3bits.MI2C2IF = 0;

    I2C2TRN = data;

    while (I2C2STATbits.TRSTAT) {};

    Nop();
    Nop();
}
```

---

What do you think about the **while** condition? Does the microchip not using a lot of CPU for that?

I asked myself this question and surprisingly saw a lot of similar code in internet.

Is there not a better way to do it?

---

What about the `Nop()` too, why two of them?

Comment: if you have nothing else to do and you have to wait for the thing to finish, then you have to just wait, and how do you wait well you poll...If yo have other things to do then you can poll every so often while you do other things or you can use an interrupt.

Comment: the two nops are probably there to kill time on the i2c bus between transactions in case you did them back to back.  They probably had an issue that violated the timing of the bus and tossed some delays in to solve it, here again, fairly typical.  You are implementing a hardware state machine in software so you have to do things like wait for this and wait for that and delay N time periods, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, in order to interact with hardware, there are 2 ways:

- Busy wait
- Interrupt base

In your case, in order to interact with the I2C device, your software is waiting first that the TBF bit is cleared which means the I2C device is ready to accept a byte to send.
Then your software is actually writing the byte into the device and waits that the TRSTAT bit is cleared, meaning that the data has been correctly processed by your I2C device.

The code your are showing is written with busy wait loops, meaning that the CPU is actively waiting the HW. This is indeed waste of resources, but in some case (e.g. your I2C interrupt line is not connected or not available) this is the only way to do.

If you would use interrupt, you would ask the hardware to tell you whenever a given event is happening. For instance, TBF bit is cleared, etc...
The advantage of that is that, while the HW is doing its stuff, you can continue doing other. Or just sleep to save battery.

I'm not an expert in I2C so the interrupt event I have described is most likely not accurate, but that gives you an idea why you get 2 while loop.

Now regarding pro and cons of interrupt base implementation and busy wait implementation I would say that interrupt based implementation is more efficient but more difficult to write since you have to process asynchronous event coming from HW. Busy wait implementation is easy to write but is slower; But this might still be fast enough for you.

Eventually, I got no idea why the 2 NoP are needed there. Most likely a tweak which is needed because somehow, the CPU would still go too fast.

Comment: a third option which you rarely see is the hardware does the wait for you which nicely matches the polling.  you perform a write to do the operation or a read to read status, that read holds the processor bus until the operation is complete.  I have seen it but can count on less than five fingers the number of times I have seen it personally.  Normally it is poll or interrupt.

Comment: another implementation is actually how hardware does work.  writes are or can be fire and forget for example, the memory controller can take the address and data and free the processor THEN go off and take time doing the write, but they can only buffer so many.  If you do too many writes (could be as few as 2 depends on the design) they may have to hold off the processor until they have room in their write buffer to store another.  Could build a peripheral that way too, but you dont normally see that.

Comment: Pretty interesting!

I hope to see that in my career of embedded system engineer :D

Comment: write buffering is on the back of many caches or even without caches, it is fairly common.  as far as the other, as a system engineer you can ask/tell the chip/fpga designer to do that if/when you are in that position.  And/or learn verilog and just do it yourself.   It has side effects of coarse, holding off the processor like that, but some dma engines will hold the processor off as well.

Comment: In this case, an interrupt implementation would be much less efficient as all the time spent entering and exiting interrupt contexts (not to mention coordinating between the application and the interrupt code through a needless buffer) would never compensate for the few instructions spent spinning.

Comment: All theses things are highly interesting indeed. Thank you very much for the times you spent answering my question. Do you have any link/example/documentation about the read implementation (3rd option)?

Answer (score 1):

when doing these kinds of transactions (i2c/spi) you find yourself in one of two situations, bit bang, or some form of hardware assist.  bit bang is easier to implement and read and debug, and is often quite portable from one chip/family to the next.  But burns a lot of cpu.  But microcontrollers are mostly there to be custom hardware like a cpld or fpga that is easier to program.  They are there to burn cpu cycles pretending to be hardware designs.  with i2c or spi you are trying to create a specific waveform on some number of I/O pins on the device and at times latching the inputs. The bus has a spec and sometimes is slower than your cpu.  Sometimes not, sometimes when you add the software and compiler overhead you might end up not needing a timer for delays you might be just slow enough.  But ideally you look at the waveform and you simply create it, raise pin X delay n ms, raise pin Y delay n ms, drop pin Y delay 2*n ms, and so on.  Those delays can come from tuned loops (count from 0 to 1341) or polling a timer until it gets to Z number of ticks of some clock.  Massive cpu waste, but the point is you are really just being programmable hardware and hardware would be burning time waiting as well.

When you have a peripheral in your mcu that assists it might do much/most of the timing for you but maybe not all of it, perhaps you have to assert/deassert chip select and then the spi logic does the clock and data timing in and out for you.  And these peripherals are generally very specific to one family of one chip vendor perhaps common across a chip vendor but never vendor to vendor so very not portable and there is a learning curve.  And perhaps in your case if the cpu is fast enough it might be possible for you to do the next thing in a way that it violates the bus timing, so you would have to kill more time (maybe why you have those Nops()).

Think of an mcu as a software programmable CPLD or FPGA and this waste makes a lot more sense.  Unfortunately unlike a CPLD or FPGA you are single threaded so you cant be doing several trivial things in parallel with clock accurate timing (exactly this many clocks task a switches state and changes output).  Interrupts help but not quite the same, change one line of code and your timing changes.

In this case, esp with the nops, you should probably be using a scope anyway to see the i2c bus and since/when you have it on the scope you can try with and without those calls to see how it affects the waveform.  It could also be a case of a bug in the peripheral or a feature maybe you cant hit some register too fast otherwise the peripheral breaks. or it could be a bug in a chip from 5 years ago and the code was written for that the bug is long gone, but they just kept re-using the code, you will see that a lot in vendor libraries.

Comment: Note, sadly, clang/llvm has a problem within infinite-ish loops I have seen it break doing things similar to this, and they seem to be fine with having a broken compiler.  Doesnt break all the time, but have seen it break trying to use it on a microcontroller to poll for something (waiting for the uart tx buffer to be empty).

Comment: You can't really blame the compiler. The code is not strictly compliant to the C standard. How you make a compiler do the right thing with hardware interaction is always going to require platform-specific and compiler-specific work.

Comment: so volatile int a;  while(1) if (a!=0) break; is not legal?  if so then fair enough...Calling asm coded functions would be required then...

Comment: It's absolutely legal. But what it *means* is platform-specific. It may or may not be enough for some particular hardware application. For example, imagine a CPU that needed an explicit instruction issued to see changes to some hardware registers but not others. That's certainly possible. Should that code issue that instruction in the loop or not? The C standard doesn't say. What if it is needed only for this hardware device and the compiler writer didn't even know that this hardware existed?

Comment: in the llvm case I was calling a function in a separate optimization domain, an assembly function that they couldnt see into or predict, and the while loop operated on the return value, so it wasnt even a case of what does volatile mean, etc.  it was call this function in this loop and look at its return, cant imagine how that is vague or platform specific.

Comment: It is completely! Whether a compiler can optimize across link units is platform specific. Whether or not an optimization is *permitted* has nothing to do with whether or not any compiler is actually capable of doing that optimization. So if your argument relies on talking about what the compiler was capable of doing, it's entirely platform specific. If a theoretically perfect optimizing compiler could do it without violating the standard, then arguing that an actual compiler shouldn't do it is platform specific.

Comment: so the C language says:  if(external_function()==12) do_something.  is up to interpretation and is platform specific?  seems like a very broken language if it is wishy washy on how it implements something like that.  I assume that is not what you are trying to say.

Comment: No, that's not what I said. Read what I said again. A compiler can make any optimization that won't break code that doesn't rely on anything not in the language specification. What is needed to interact with particular hardware bits is not in the language standard. The `volatile` keyword provides a way to flag to the compiler that you need some kind of special support, but the standard does not say what, nor could it because one can imagine platforms that would have many different types of such support needed in different circumstances. A function being "external" has no portable relevance.

Answer (score 0):

> What do you think about the while condition? Does the microchip not using a lot of CPU for that?

No, since the transmit buffer won't stay full for very long.

> I asked myself this question and surprisingly saw a lot of similar code in internet.

What would you suggest instead?

> Is there not a better way to do it? (I hate crazy loops :D)

Not that I, you, or apparently anyone else knows of. In what way do you think it could be any better? The transmit buffer won't stay full long enough to make it useful to retask the CPU.

What about the Nop() too, why two of them?

The Nop's ensure that the signal remains stable long enough. This makes this code safe to call under all conditions. Without it, it would only be safe to call this code if you didn't mess with the i2c bus immediately after calling it. But in most cases, this code would be called in a loop anyway, so it makes much more sense to make it inherently safe.

Comment: I would disagree with most of the things said, sorry. If the CPU is needed to do other work, the busy polling loops are a bad idea indeed, and the transmit buffer will stay full too long relative to the the CPU speed, as the communication is pretty slow. And the better way will be to use interrupt-driven or DMA (if available) transmission.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The CPU *can't* do other work, the loops run for only a few instructions. There's no way to make use of so little time.

Comment: Thx for answering my question. I can see that there is a disagreement about how much work can a CPU perform between a register write and read. Does it exist benchmark or tests or mathematical demonstration that can prove someone to be right?

Comment: You can add a counter to the spin loop to see how many times it spins.